# about line integral evaluation

Tags: line-integrals

Any hints on which equation to use is most appreciated! I give up on thinking at 5am using my brain which is made up of mashed potatoes :)

$\int\limits_C \underline{G} \cdot d\underline{r}$ with $G(x,y) = xy \underline{i}  + 2 y^2 \underline{j} $,

and C is the closed path comprising the straight line segment from (1, 0) to (0, −1) and
three quarters of the clockwise circle of unit radius, centred at the origin, connecting
(0, −1) to (1, 0).

Comment: What do you tried?

Comment: well maybe Green's Theorem

Comment: Okay, edit the post with your attempts so we can suggest a hint

Comment: No worries I solved it, stack exchange is always quite helpful :)